# How to create java bean configuration from XML for parent bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean

I have following XML bean configuration which I need to convert to Java based configuration

```
   <bean id="baseBook" class="com.practice.Book" >
       <property name="bookName" value="First book" />
   </bean>
   <bean id="bookBean" class="com.practice.ChildBook" parent="baseBook">
       <property name="bookAuthor" value="Raj" />
       <property name="bookPrice" value="200" />
   </bean>
```

**Something like below:**

```
@Bean
   public ChildBook bookBean(){
        ChildBook bookBean = new ChildBook();
        bookBean.setBookAuthor("Raj");
        bookBean.setBookPrice(200);
        return bookBean;    
   }
      
   @Bean
   public Book baseBook(){
        Book book = new Book();
        book.setBookName("First book");
        return book;
   }
```

However, I am not able to set `bookName` for `ChildBook`. I checked some solutions which suggests to create new `init` method and call it in bookBean(). But I am looking for more acurate/convenient solution. Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no replacement for that in Java.

Comment: @M.Deinum no replacement for init() method solution or no solution to the problem at all?

Comment: There is no **direct** replacement for parent beans in java-config. So the solution you checked isn't a solution for this. The best you could do, if `ChildBook` extends `Book`, is create a method which you call with the newly created `ChildBook` . However that only works if there is also a hierarchy in Java, else it won't work.